# Git equivalent of svn tag custom properties

Tags: svn, properties, tags, migration, git-svn

I actually plan to migrate svn repo to git repo. But the svn tags contain specific properties, something like my:v.states with values between internal staging, custom staging, tested, ...

What is the best solution to represent that information in git repository?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best solution to represent that information in git repository?

Branches.

1st, get OK with the idea that your *existing workflows* will not survive the migration. You, the whole your team, all your svn-touching robots (CI systems etc), will need to learn and adapt.

Next, please see Git Flow for an example and a starting point: https://leanpub.com/git-flow/read

You don't *have* to cargo-cult Git Flow by trying to reproduce 100% of it. Embrace the ideas, then work out a workflow that will work best for *your needs*.

For what little of your needs you've revealed, I'd suggest *modifying your workflow* to rely on a top-level `TEST_REPORT.json` file: the engineers stamp their *Tested on <env1>, <env2>, <env3>* approvals into that file, the file can naturally be different in each branch, the file travels together with code changes when merging.

You don't inherently *need* commit attributes to implement that. A simple file is enough.